# Python - Move key position and make some calculations with the values

Tags: python, json

Given the following code:

```
data= [
{
    "2021-03-06": [
        3.1,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "2021-03-07": [
        23,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "2021-03-08": [
        15.7,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "2021-03-09": [
        18.86,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "id": 8601
}
```

]

```
final_data=[
    {
        "2021-03-06": 7.41,
        "2021-03-07": 0.68,
        "2021-03-08": 1.20,
        "id": 8601
    }
]
```

Convert data to final_data:

- How can the id key be moved to the first position of the array?
- Based on the key "time" (it is already ordered per day); how can be
  replaced the value of each date as only 1 (not like now, that there
  are 3 values), diving the first value of the next date between the
  first current value. *The last value of the array could not be
  calculated as there is not a next value in the array (it should be
  removed).  An example of the first value calculation: 23/3.1=7,41

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
>>data
    [{'2021-03-06': [3.1, 0, 0], '2021-03-07': [23, 0, 0], '2021-03-08': [15.7, 0, 0], '2021-03-09': [18.86, 0, 0], 'id': 8601}]

>>finalData = []
>>temp = {}
>>for i in range(len(keys)-2):
    temp[keys[i]] = data[0][keys[i+1]] / data[0][keys[i]]
>>temp['id'] = data[0]['id']
>>finalData.append(temp)
>>finalData
[{'2021-03-06': 7.419354838709677, '2021-03-07': 0.6826086956521739, '2021-03-08': 1.2012738853503184, 'id': 8601}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array **data**. Your array contains just one dictionary. That means that you can't order the keys into dictionary, because a dictionary not has **order** idea.
You can pop the id from the dictionary if it is necessary to order it into array data, NOT into the dictionary of array data.

If you must to have the id into your object, don't care, your id is "ordered". You need to care how to dump into json file to put id first.

```
my_items = sorted([my_item for my_item in data[0].items() if my_item[0] != 'id'], key=lambda my_it: my_it[0])
i = 1
while i < len(my_items):
    data[0].update({my_items[i-1][0]: round(my_items[i][1][0] / my_items[i-1][1][0], 2)})
    i += 1
```

You need to sort your data, because dictionary not garantize ordered data even if you see them ordered.

Regards.